# Getting current Location in Android API level 23

Tags: android, dictionary, android-studio

Hello i am completely new in android location concept, i have created one map activity in android studio. this is the code.

```
 public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        Location location = null;
        LatLng currentPosition = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(currentPosition).title("Current Location"));
```

Is this is correct @Abhishek

Comment: just add following line :    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

Comment: Seems it already answered in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145089/what-is-the-simplest-and-most-robust-way-to-get-the-users-current-location-on-a?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://ramsandroid4all.blogspot.in/2015/05/showing-current-location-with-marker-in.html

Comment: @Elina just check my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like this

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    LatLng currentPosition = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(currentPosition).title("Current Location"));
}
```

`location` which get from `onLocationChanged` method

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
 location = new LatLng(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude());

 ----------

}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked but problem is It is not visible in marker, can you help me out for that how to use marker for my location..

Comment: what is that location, from where u  got that ? where you have initialize "location".. @Abhishek

Comment: public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);


        Location location = null;
        LatLng currentPosition = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(currentPosition).title("Current Location"));

Comment: hello @Abhishek please can you give complete code, i am too new to understand. where i have to define the location can you please give in one class everything please..

Comment: please refer this http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/